# Passing parameters in embedded sql in a shell script

Tags: sql, linux, unix

Can someone please help me with this. I am calling this function with a parameter. The function's role is to connect to a database and store the result of the sql in SQL_RESULT.
I am not sure if using (WHERE ACQ = '$1') is correct, i.e. will $1 be successfully replaced by ACQ_NAME that I have passed to the function?
P.S. This is not the full script, I have just provided relevant info only from the script.
Thanks in advance.

```
#!/bin/ksh

function get_aq_info
{
    SQL_RESULT=`sqlplus -s $DBNAME <<EOF
            set verify off;
            set heading off;
            set feedback off;
            SELECT *
            FROM CV_ACQ
            WHERE ACQ = '$1';
    quit;
EOF`
}

#MAIN

get_aq_info ACQ_NAME
```

Comment: Why don't you simply try it?

Comment: **1**: do not use backticks to run commands, use `$()`.  **2** remove the `'` arount `$1`.  Variable expansion does not occur when surrounded by `'`.